# SSH key pairs for bitbucket - can pull but not push

Tags: linux, ssh, bitbucket

I use Bitbucket for all my repos and mostly my master source is on a local Windows machine - I have no problem with pushing and pulling in that context. However I have one project where I am coding on a remote Linux/Ubuntu machine and I have tried all ways I can think of to create and set SSH key pairs. But whatever I do, I cannot push code back to the repo without the message "Unauthorized fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists".

I have run ssh-keygen and pasted the public key to Bitbucket - both as a site specific key and also as an overall key in the account settings (I have it in both places now).

I can pull without any problem but push generates the auth error.

Suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: This is a programming question. I am a programmer and I am trying to get my code safely into its repository.